# How do i get the x-th largest and y-th smallest value of a Priority Queue Heap?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

How do i get the x-th largest and y-th smallest value of a Priority Queue Heap? I know there are MIN and MAX from the standart STL library but they dont quite do the job for me...

In other words for example i need to get the second smallest value and the third largest value in a Priority Queue Heap that contains lets say 10 variables. I need to compare the variables which I can push in a vector.

Comment: You can pop the first min / max value, to get to the next one. See example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-min-heap-using-stl/)

Comment: @SubMachine To be honest i think i need to compare the elemets. My idea was to push them in a vector and use Max-heap for example then get the indexes of the elements but the problem with that is that vectors count from index [0] and its going to mess up the rest of the numbers..

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

Comment: @Vap0ur3x, I think you should edit your question and describe the problem in more details.

Comment: What you do with the elements (push to a vector) is irrelevant. Your heap is ordered by min or max; not both. For a min heap (smallest at the top) of size N, the nth smallest requires enumeration through n elements The m'th largest requires enumeration through N-m elements. There are no shortcuts to that. That you desire indexed elements from a priority queue (opposed to what a priority queue is intended to be: a box where the queue condition always answers correctly for the top element and you don't care about the rest) suggests a heap-based queue is not the container you need.

Comment: If there's fewer than 10 elements, the container and O(n) efficiency don't really matter. You need random access on a sorted container, which doesn't exist in the standard library, so either use a vector and sort it, or use a set and iterate N times.